# Print Given Character Surrounded by Smileys

Tags: java, arrays

How would I print the given character surrounded by smiley's? Here is what I have so far but it just prints a long horizontal string.

```
public class Smileys {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        printWithSmileys("\\:D/");
        printWithSmileys("92.");

    }

    private static void printWithSmileys(String characterString) {
        for (int i = 0; i < characterString.length(); i++) {
            int numberOfSmileys = characterString.charAt(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSmileys; j++) {
                System.out.print(":)");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

The output should look like this.

```
:):):):):)
:) \:D/ :)
:):):):):)
:):):):):)
:) 92.  :)
:):):):):)
```

Comment: Your code looks nothing like your requested output... Why do you expect that output?

Comment: `int numberOfSmileys = characterString.charAt(i);` seems blatantly wrong.

Comment: I did the int numberOfSmileys = characterString.charAt(i); because I was trying to get the location/length of the character String so I could print smiley's around it. Sorry I am very new to Java and am having a difficult time trying to wrap my head around printing characters through loops.

Comment: What does your output currently look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution with comments. Have fun :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    printWithSmileys("\\:D/");
    printWithSmileys("92.");

}

private static void printWithSmileys(String string) {
    // Find the length of our line in smiley 
    // (smiley length is 2 so we divide by 2 and add one to round up)
    int length = (string.length()+1)/2;
    // Add one smiley on each side, plus 2 smiley
    length += 2;
    // Add one smiley for the two spaces surrounding our string
    length += 1;
    // Add one space if length is an odd number
    if (string.length()%2 != 0)
        string += " ";

    //Print first line
    printSmileyLine(length);

    //Print middle line
    System.out.print(":) ");
    System.out.print(string);
    System.out.print(" :)");
    System.out.println("");

    //Print last line
    printSmileyLine(length);
}

/**
 * Print length smiley 
 */
private static void printSmileyLine(int length) {
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        System.out.print(":)");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this. Just brieftly why did you do the string += ""; below the first if statement?

Comment: if (string.length()%2 != 0) string += " "; There i add one space in case the string length is an odd number like "92.". If you dont add the space the last smiley of the middle line will not be aligned with other lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void printWithSmileys(String characterString) {
    for (int i = 0; i < characterString.length(); i++) {
        int numberOfSmileys = characterString.charAt(i);
```

You'll have a compile error here String.charAt(int index) returns a char and it can't be set to an int data type.

```
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSmileys; j++) {
            System.out.print(":)");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

I think what you want is...

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print(":)")
        for (int j = 0; j < characterString.length(); j++) {
            if(i % 2 != 0){
                 if(j == 0 || j == characterString.length()-1){
                      System.out.print(":)");
                 }else{
                      System.out.print(characterString.charAt(j-1));
                 }
            }else{
                 System.out.print(":)");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Not tested but good place to start.

Comment: Great thanks. It gives an error at characterString.charAt but it's an excellent way to re-start. I forgot about the modulo to check to see if a length is negative.